# How to manage two objects with different speed in surface views

Tags: surfaceview

How to handle speed of two different objects drawn in surface Views.
Do I have to make two different threads for it and use sleep ? Or is there any other option to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to make something like that, if you want two objects to be updated at different speeds you can fake it, like have a counter and every time the object is updated (or drawn depending what you want) to change every x frames. For example you want objectA to update every 2 frames, do this:

```
//Every frame
counter++;
if (counter >= 2)
{
    counter = 0;
    //Update or Draw
}
```

Do the same for objectB if needed.
You were not very specific what you meant by "different speeds" so that was the best I could think of, if your case is different let me know :)